# galleria javascript crops topand bootom of images when viewing in Firefox Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, galleria

galleria javascript crops top and base of images when viewing in Firefox Chrome and IE

However in Safari this issue does not exist.

Please see the issue here 
http://galleria.aino.se/media/galleria/src/themes/fullscreen/fullscreen-demo.html

no compare the squirrel image with its original 
right click on any image and you will see how the script is not displaying the the full image.

We are using galleria. js full screen for a wordpress theme and all our images are the same size so there is no height issue the images we will use are 1600x900

If any one can help please advise. We need to display the entire image.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's how galleria is supposed to behave. In full screen mode it fills the screen, so it will crop the top or sides, whichever extends beyond the aspect ratio of the browser window.

In full-screen mode, if you have a wide browser window, it'll crop the top/bottom. If you resize the browser window to portrait orientation, it'll crop the left/right.

Answer (score 0):

You can control this behavior using the image_crop option.

F.ex if you want the image to always fit, set this to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set in your css:

```
.galleria-image img {max-width:6000px !important;}
```

this works for me, I think there is some trouble in Safari with the attribute max-width of the image. You could use this simple trick or improve this technique adding some conditional css, so for example setting max-width to a specific value only when option "imageCrop" of galleria is set to true. Let me know if this works also for you!